# ceuicu.exe file found on my PC

Tags: windows-10, virus

I've recently noticed that there is a task called `ceuicu.exe` running. I also noticed that it listed in the files to load when booting up with a high startup impact. I located that `exe` file at `C:\Users\Username\ceuicu.exe`. I have no clue what this file do and how it got into my PC so I tried to decompile it.

The decompiled file is a very long 10k lines of C code (seems like it was written in VB) which I have no clue what it does. I then tried to manually delete the exe file but I can't see it in the windows explorer window. I tried to enable hidden files view but I still can't see it. I then tried using the CMD to and when I run the command `dir /A` I can see it there.

I tried deleting the file running the command `del ceuicu.exe` but I always get the message that this couldn't be found: `Could Not Find C:\Users\Username\ceuicu.exe"`.

Eventually I used Avast to delete that file.

Has anyone encountered this exe file before?

Comment: There is a virus where one of the names is `ceuicu.scr`. Perhaps it is related? https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/869bb9942df641b4847c86493c59de6857758181230ec9e785fb0889e5f5d5f4/analysis/. If you still have a copy of the file you could submit it to https://www.virustotal.com/ and see if it is the same vurus.

Comment: If it's 10k lines of C code then it couldn't have been written in VB...